# What are alternative cache solutions to Output Cache in asp.net MVC3?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

What are the alternative solutions to Output Cache in asp.net MVC3? I don't know whether its the only one or there are other alternative solutions and hence asked. This is just for gk, and not a technical question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own cache provider or use third parties.

Examples:

- MemCached http://memcached.org/
- NCache http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/
- AppFabric

Output cache is just an attribute with some logic that talks to the cache provider. You can implement your own attribute which will talk to the cache provider of your choice.